# Check for the existence of a record on multiple tables

Tags: sql, entity-framework

My Column is `ART.CODE`the other tables are CST,CSTTD,ACQ,SCON,PROMO
in these tables "Code" is called "U_Code". Code can be null in these secondary tables. I have to verify the existence of "Code" in at least one of the secondary tables, I tried to use left join but it always restores a value because Code in the table "ART" is never null ... I have no idea how to do it if don't use as many queries as there are tables in question and at the first match stop me.

Comment: add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: It is not possible to PREVENT this situation as by definition U_CODE is a foreign key to ART.code.  It is possible however to get the list where this condition is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the ART.UCODE then using a correlated subquery with `not exists` 
seems to me to be the "Best"  This ensures a ART.CODE doesn't exist in any of the secondary tables U_CODE fields.  In the correlation we don't care what data is returned only that a match is found or not.  All we're doing here is ensuring for a given ART.CODE it doesn't exist in any of the secondary tables.   The engine can early exist once a single match is found; unlike a left join.

I would expect this approach to be more performant and easiest to maintain especially if U_CODE is a foreign key in each table making it indexed.

```
SELECT ART.CODE
FROM ART
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM CST WHERE ART.CODE = CST.U_CODE)
  and not exists (SELECT 1 FROM CSTTD WHERE ART.CODE = CSTTD.U_CODE)
  and not exists (SELECT 1 FROM ACQ WHERE ART.CODE = ACQ.U_CODE)
  and not exists (SELECT 1 FROM SCON WHERE ART.CODE = SCON.U_CODE)
  and not exists (SELECT 1 FROM PROMO WHERE ART.CODE = PROMO.U_CODE)
```

You could simply left join coalesce and check for a NULL after coalescing all the ucodes.  If no u_code exists in any table, null will be returned from the coalesce and those are the ones you're after.

However as you've not defined how these tables interrelate this may result in many more records than needed as I don't know what the actual relationships are and performance will suffer.

```
SELECT ART.CODE
FROM ART 
LEFT JOIN CST
 on ART.CODE = CST.U_CODE
LEFT JOIN CSTTD
 on ART.CODE = CSTTD.U_CODE
LEFT JOIN ACQ
 on ART.CODE = ACQ.U_CODE
LEFT JOIN SCON
 on ART.CODE = SCON.U_CODE
LEFT JOIN PROMO
 on ART.CODE = PROMO.U_CODE
WHERE coalesce(CST.UCODE, CSTTD.UCODE, QCQ.U_CODE, SCON.U_CODE, SCON.U_CODE) is null
```

A 3rd way, just because I'm having fun, would be to union the results of all the sub tables and then check for any u_Code existence.  But performance wise the implicit distinct done on the union negates the index usage so this would be slow depending on volume of records; but I like it better than all those left joins from a maintenance aspect and that coalesce seems so hackish.

```
SELECT ART.CODE
FROM ART 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT U_CODE FROM CST UNION
           SELECT U_CODE FROM CSTTD UNION
           SELECT U_CODE FROM ACQ  UNION
           SELECT U_CODE FROM SCON UNION
           SELECT U_CODE FROM PROMO) Z
  on ART.CODE = Z.U_CODE
WHERE Z.U_CODE Is null
```